# Taking command line options in C

Tags: c, command-line, getopt

I have a hash table program and i'm trying to implement command line option inputs. The default action is to create a hash table and read in a text file, this is done after checking the options. The options mostly alter the properties of the hash table before its creation, e.g the -f option specifies table size.

e.g `./program < words.txt -f 400`

I'm currently handling them like this:

```
int main(int argc, char*argv[]){

    const char *optstring = "e:f:";
    char option;
    int tablesize = 100;
    int unknown_words, i;
    char word[256];
    htable h;   
    default = 1;

    while((option = getopt(argc, argv, optstring)) != EOF){
        switch (option){

            case 'e':
                default = 0;
                h = htable_new(tablesize);

                copy_in(h);

                unknown_words = find_words(h, optarg);
                printf("%d", unknown_words);
                break;

             case 'f':

                if(optarg && atoi(optarg)>0){   
                    tablesize = atoi(optarg);           
                }
                break;
        }
     }

     if(default==1){
         h = htable_new(tablesize);
         copy_in(h);
         print_stats(h);
     }
  }
```

My issue is that I want to enter these flags/options in any order. I have an option -e that takes an argument (the name of a second text file). It creates a hash table and reads in the first text file (like the default action) then searches the hash table for the words in the second file and prints the unknown number of words.
I also have an option -f that specifies to use a different table size than the default. If run with the below command I get expected behaviour.

```
./program < words.txt -f 350 -e other_words.txt
```

The -f option is found first and the tablesize variable is changed from its default value to the given 350. The -e option is then found and carried out using this updated value.

However in a different order with the same desired behaviour:

```
./program < words.txt -e other_words.txt -f 350
```

The -e option is carried out on the default table size and only afterwards is the -f option found and the tablesize changed and then not used.

I've done the below which works but seems inefficient. Essentially if the -e option is found, loop through the remaining options and do them first. This means duplicate code for each relevant option though and i'm curious how else to handle this.

```
 while((option = getopt(argc, argv, optstring)) != EOF){
        switch (option){

            case 'e':
                default = 0;
                for(i=optind;i<argc;i++){
                    if(strcmp(argv[i],"-t") == 0){
                        if(argv[i+1] && atoi(argv[i+1])>0){ 
                            tablesize =atoi(argv[i+1]);
                        }
                     }
                 }


                h = htable_new(tablesize);

                copy_in(h);

                unknown_words = find_words(h, optarg);
                printf("%d", unknown_words);
                break;

             case 'f':

                if(optarg && atoi(optarg)>0){   
                    tablesize = atoi(optarg);           
                }
                break;
        }
     }
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow. Please take a look at [mcve] on how to reduce your code to better clarify what it is your asking.

Comment: There technically wasn't a question in there. Please don't keep us guessing and ask something concrete after all that beautiful exposition.

Comment: If order matters you have to gather all of your arguments first and once you have all, run the respective codes. If you have the option `f` set `tablesize` (initialize to something that cannot happen, e.g.: -1), if you have option `e` put the filename somewhere (initialize to e.g.: NULL ).  After the option-loop check for `tablesize != -1` and set that size, check for `filename != NULL` and work that file.

Comment: I don't know if I understand the problem correctly, but why not go _option by option_ and save the data. You're doing it in the `-f` option. When you recieve `-e` you can just annotate the name/path and after storing the options, execute the `htable_new` and other functions / routines.

Comment: You will need to think about what would happen if the user ran `./program -f 300 -e whatever.out -f 350 -e another.out`.  The `getopt()` function will return the options and arguments in sequence — your code has to make sure that it does something sensible.  There are lots of possible sensible courses of action — use the first occurrence of an option, use the last, report an error on repeating an option, and so on.  What's best to do depends on what the program is designed to do, and to some extent who you expect your users to be.

Comment: Hi, Please do not deface your post after you have taken help from it. It is like cutting down a tree after taking shelter below it. Please allow the other future users to gain from the knowledge. The answerers would have put a lot of effort. Do not put their valuable time to waste.

Answer (score 3):

The typical approach would be not do actual work in the option handlers; instead let each handler set a variable to keep track that the option was specified (and what its argument was).  Then after you parse all command line options, can process them in whatever order you want.  For example, something like:

```
const char* filename = NULL;
int tablesize = 0;

while ((option = getopt(argc, argv, optstring)) != EOF) {
    switch (option) {
        case 'e':
            filename = optarg;
            break;

         case 'f':
            if (optarg && atoi(optarg) > 0) {
                tablesize = atoi(optarg);           
            }
            break;
    }
}

if (filename != NULL) {
    default = 0;
    h = htable_new(tablesize);

    copy_in(h);
    unknown_words = find_words(h, filename);
    printf("%d", unknown_words);
}
```